# Is there a way to turn on indicator that a directory item is a shell script in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash

When I do an ls of a directory and a shell script is listed as a directory item, is there a way I can have a visual indication that it is a shell script ?

For example:

```
From /opt/local/bin 
ls -l
```

Displays port from MacPorts as an ordinary item:

```
port
```

Can I have color coding, bold or some other way to see this ?  I know I can use file to check if it's a script, executable, etc., but that's an extra command I have to issue and is no better than trying to run port and then getting an error and typing ./port.

Thanks!

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try typing `ls -G` in terminal, you should see colored listings by file type.  If the scripts aren't being shown in a different color, this means that they are not marked as executable, so you will need to type `sudo chmod +x <filename>` to make them so.  Then they should appear in a different color as opposed to directorys etc.

If you prefer not to always type ls -G then you can put the following command in your `.bashrc` file in your home directory  `alias "ls"="ls -G"`  Then restart terminal and you should see colored output whenever you just type `ls`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an environment variable that controls ls's color options. That would be the better thing to change

Comment: @Fake Name - Thanks guys!  This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this in your `~/.bash_profile` file to enable colors equivalent to `ls -G`:

```
#!/bin/sh
export CLICOLOR=1
```

Answer (score 1):

As I’m not a fan of colours — they depend on the current terminal colour settings to look good — I prefer to use `ls -F`.

Borrowing from SCO Unix, I define an `lf` alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias lf="ls -F"
```

Executable files such as shell scripts show up with a `*` at the end of their names. Similarly, `/` for directories and `@` for symbolic links.

Comment: Thanks!  The color highlighting was what I was looking for, but I had no idea of the asterisk option - I'll add this to my toolkit.